# Subtract mean of columns grouped by one column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas DataFrame which looks as follows:

```
data = {'user_id':[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        'time':[10, 12, 11, 20, 40, 41, 42, 100, 60, 22, 0, 3],
        'height':[1.23, 1.1, 0.5, 10.3, 3.33, 4.55, 2.22, 2.21, 2.25, 7.75, 9.2, 5.5],
        'width':[3, 4, 6, 2, 4, 8, 9, 0, 6, 6, 6, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now, I would like to subtract from every column (except the `user_id` column) the mean value grouped by `user_id`. That means for `user_id` 1 the mean value for `time` is 13.25 ((10 + 12 + 11 + 20) / 4), so 13.25 is subtracted from 10, 12, 11 and 20 leading to

```
'time':[-3.25, -1.25, -2.25, 6.75, 40, 41, 42, 100, 60, 22, 0, 3]
```

This I would like to do for all columns and all users. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
df[df.columns.difference(['user_id'])].sub(df.groupby('user_id').transform('mean'))
```

---

From @piRSquare:

```
df.update(df - df.groupby('user_id').transform('mean'))
```

or

```
df.loc[:, ['height', 'time', 'width']] -= df.groupby('user_id').transform('mean')
```

---

From @anky_91:

```
df.drop('user_id',1).sub(df.groupby('user_id').time.transform('mean'),axis=0)


Out[2054]:
      height   time  width
0  -2.052500  -3.25  -0.75
1  -2.182500  -1.25   0.25
2  -2.782500  -2.25   2.25
3   7.017500   6.75  -1.75
4  -0.036667  -1.00  -3.00
5   1.183333   0.00   1.00
6  -1.146667   1.00   2.00
7  -3.172000  63.00  -4.40
8  -3.132000  23.00   1.60
9   2.368000 -15.00   1.60
10  3.818000 -37.00   1.60
11  0.118000 -34.00  -0.40
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. Do I have to state each column explicitly or is it possible to apply it to all columns except user_id column without providing the column names?

Comment: `df.loc[:, ['height', 'time', 'width']] -= df.groupby('user_id').transform('mean')`

Comment: More succinct `df.update(df - df.groupby('user_id').transform('mean'))`

Comment: @piRSquared: great, you are the master. Thumbs up!

Comment: or `df.drop('user_id',1).sub(df.groupby('user_id').time.transform('mean'),axis=0)`

Comment: @anky_91: good one. I never think about drop `user_id` before `sub`. Added yours to the answer :). +1

Answer (score 4):

You can use `groupby.transform` to create an array same shape as your dataframe. Then substract that from your `time` column:

```
m = df.groupby('user_id')['time'].transform('mean')

df['time'].add(-m)
```

---

```
0     -3.25
1     -1.25
2     -2.25
3      6.75
4     -1.00
5      0.00
6      1.00
7     63.00
8     23.00
9    -15.00
10   -37.00
11   -34.00
Name: time, dtype: float64
```

Output of m results in:

```
print(m)

0     13.25
1     13.25
2     13.25
3     13.25
4     41.00
5     41.00
6     41.00
7     37.00
8     37.00
9     37.00
10    37.00
11    37.00
Name: time, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This is not matching with OP's output!

Comment: I have shown the output for the time column only for user_id 1, so I think it is matching

Comment: Can this be also applied to all columns (except user_id column) without stating each column explicitly?

Comment: @machinery: check my answer

Comment: @shaikmoeed it is correct. The OP's output only shows one subtraction. Also, it could be written: `df.time -=  df.groupby('user_id').time.transform('mean')`.

Comment: @QuangHoang I totally agree that output is correct. OP wants to do same with all columns as Andy L has answered.

Comment: For me the goal is not always to make "one-liners" but readable and understandable code @QuangHoang

Comment: I Have not hình against that. But I guest everyone has different perspectives about *readable*. Cheers.